# GoogleCloudMessaging.register(SENDER_ID ) returns null

Tags: android, mobile, push-notification

i am facing issue with registering device with GoogleCloudMessaging for push notifications

the source code can be found here:

https://github.com/ronenhamias/ezPushSDK-Android

the problem i am facing it that calling register to device returns null 70% of the times some time the registration succeed mainly when i am using the android studio emulator but when another developer runs the app or debugging it on a real device it returns null

please note that i created the project and got sender id and api key and was able to push with this keys several times.

for some reason the integration with the cloud returns null.no error is thrown, and no further information is provided

what can be the reasons for that?

Comment: register id null all time in devices? are you check internet

Answer (score 0):

Hope It work for You..
Please change

```
 <receiver android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
```

TO

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
```

And If It not Then Use GCM.jar file and change **IntentService** to extends **GCMBaseIntentService** and use its default methods..
Its easy and simple to use..

and refer this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)  so You can easy to understand